# How to solve problem with html&css background on ios devices?

Tags: html, css

My problem is that when someone opens the website on an ios device, it only shows a blurry enlarged image, but it works fine on android devices. Is there some extra code for safari or ios devices (like -webkit-;-moz-)? Thanks for any response.

```
.mainpage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #0000007a 0%, var(--gray) 70%), url("img/background2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `background-position: fixed;` with `background-size: cover;`. Use `background-position: center;`  instead.

Comment: Check out the caniuse: https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attach - specifically the Known Issues tab.